# how to access data from html template to quasar vue.js component

Tags: html, vue.js, quasar-framework

Here I have html template. in that template I am accessing dynamic data by using Django from backend. By using this symbol "{{}}". So here i want to access these values in quasar pagination. I want to make pagination using vue.js. I am trying to integrate these values in vue.js component for making a pagination in vue.js. How can we merge these template values in vue.js script

**html template**

```
 <div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Member</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% if msg_list %}
        {% for i in msg_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <a>{{i.username|first|upper}}<span>{{i.username|last|upper}}</span></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <div>{{i.ttle}}</div>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <div>{{i.message}}</div>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <div>
                    {% for key,value in some_date.items %}
                    {% if i.id == key %}
                    <a>{{ value }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <button><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </tbody>
```

**quasar vue.js component**

```
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-lg flex flex-center">
    <q-pagination
      v-model="current"
      :max="5"
      direction-links
      boundary-links
      icon-first="skip_previous"
      icon-last="skip_next"
      icon-prev="fast_rewind"
      icon-next="fast_forward"
    ></q-pagination>
  </div>
</div>
```

**vue.js script**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      current: 1,
      username:'',
      ttle:'',
      message:'',
      value:'',
      
      
    }
  },
   methods: {

   },
})
```

Comment: Could you render the data from django into `vue js data () {`